# Hover not working using jquery

Tags: jquery, hover, scrolltop

I'm using below jquery code to change navbar background. Additionally I need to change some font colors. The issue is that hover from this code is not working. Why?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var top=$(window).scrollTop()
 if(top>10){
    $('.navbar').css('background-color','#ffffff');
    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus').css('border','2px solid #d3041c');
    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover').css('color','#da2027');     
    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:link').css('color','#777777');
}
 else{ 
    $('.navbar').css('background-color','rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)');      
    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus').css('border','2px solid #ffffff');
    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:link').css('color','#ffffff');  
    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover').css('color','#da2027');  
 }

  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to select all hovered elements and change their font colour, but there is nothing hovered during scrolling. You can create two css classes instead, and add them to li elements

```
$('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li').addClass('class1'); 
$('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li').removeClass('class2'); 

.class1 a:hover{
    color: #da2027;
}
.class1 a:link{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.class2 a:hover{
    color: #777777;
}
.class2 a:link{
    color: #da2027;
}
```

Comment: #Nadia: I'm afraid that this solution doesn't work. Nothing happened.

Comment: Thanks. I had to only add !important suffix'es to the colors

Comment: And I've just made a fiddle for you :) OK, glad it helped!